# How to use a container (CSS) to "wrap" a twitter embed to size to my own specs

Tags: html, css

The question is also more broadly asking how to "in-line" CSS into the HTML. Without the CSS, i can render the twitter feed the way twitter desires, but when i attempt to CSS to wrap to my own specs, I can't get the link to render. (5 days new to HTML/CSS...)

code copied below:

```
<style>
   .twitterContainer {
    width: 50%;
   height:auto;
   }
</style>

   <div class="twitterContainer">
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="100%" data-height="auto" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Twitter_Dev </a>
   </div>
       <script>
               async src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"
           charset = "utf-8" >
       </script>
```

Comment: Your script html is broken. Might want to fix that up.

Comment: Anddd that did the trick. Much appreciated. I will attempt to use the browser debugger in the source next time--it would have clearly pointed toward the error. Many thanks!